# Scroll panel auto hide inside components

Tags: vb.net, winforms

My code works, but The problem is I put a listbox in it. I want to make sure that even when the user hovers over the list box, the pane will close.

I am having 2 issues:

1. MAIN ISSUE: The panel's timers are not working because the listbox component is sort of blocking it out. I am unsure how to counteract this.
2. I want to hide or collapse the listbox for visual appeal.

Here is my code:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Panel1.Dock = DockStyle.Left
    End Sub


    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        If Panel1.Width < 150 Then
            Panel1.Width = Panel1.Width + 100
        ElseIf Panel1.Width = 150 Then
            Timer1.Enabled = False
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
        If Panel1.Width >= 100 Then
            Panel1.Width = Panel1.Width - 50
            If Panel1.Width < 100 And Panel1.Width > 25 Then
                Panel1.Width = Panel1.Width - 15
            End If

        ElseIf Panel1.Width <= 25 Then
            Timer2.Enabled = False
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Panel1_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Panel1.MouseEnter
        Timer1.Enabled = True
        Timer2.Enabled = False
    End Sub


    Private Sub Panel1_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Panel1.MouseLeave
        Timer1.Enabled = False
        Timer2.Enabled = True
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: I am not sure if it works the way it suppose to. e.g `If Panel1.Width < 50 And Panel1.Width > 25` is always false!

Comment: why do you say that? what if Panel1.Width was 40?

Comment: If it was 40 then `If Panel1.Width > 100 Then` is false too!

Comment: To be more precise, if `If Panel1.Width < 50 And Panel1.Width > 25` is ever executed, it will always produce false.

Comment: It is unreachable, you are correct. I will edit it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ListBox will cause the panel's MouseEnter and MouseLeave events to fire.

So comment out those events:

```
'Private Sub Panel1_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Panel1.MouseEnter
'    Timer1.Enabled = True
'    Timer2.Enabled = False
'End Sub

'Private Sub Panel1_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Panel1.MouseLeave
'    Timer1.Enabled = False
'    Timer2.Enabled = True
'End Sub
```

Then try adding a third timer to track the mouse over the panel:

```
Private Sub Timer3_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer3.Tick
  If Panel1.ClientRectangle.Contains(Panel1.PointToClient(MousePosition)) Then
    If Not Timer1.Enabled AndAlso Panel1.Width < 150 Then
      Timer1.Enabled = True
      Timer2.Enabled = False
    End If
  Else
    If Not Timer2.Enabled AndAlso Panel1.Width > 25 Then
      Timer1.Enabled = False
      Timer2.Enabled = True
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This isn't working right now. Am I missing something. This makes nothing happen. I want the panel to slide! I just want to make the listbox inside the panel to be invisible before it slides open (expands)

Comment: @StreamingBits Make sure the third timer is enabled.  It should be running all the time.

Comment: problem with hiding ListBox though! I will figure it out

Comment: @StreamingBits That would probably be a new question if you can't figure it out.  I made a minor update to the answer.